# Error in fetching array in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting error in fetching the data from the table with the prepared statements. Yes, I'm new in prepared statements. Any body got the solution or I'm doing it wrong?

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $student_rollno = $_SESSION['student_roll'];

 require('../includes/connect.php');

 $stmnt = $conn->prepare("SELECT students.roll, students.firstname, students.lastname, students.course, students.semester FROM students,teachers WHERE students.roll = ? AND students.semester = teachers.semester ");


$stmnt->bind_param('i',$student_rollno);

if ($stmnt->execute()){
$result = $stmnt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $student_roll = $row["0"];
    $student_name = $row["1"];
    $student_course = $row["2"];
    $student_semester = $row["3"];
     ?>



     <h1>Hello <?php echo $student_roll; ?>. Your details are : </h1><br><br>
        <h2>Roll No : <?php echo $student_name ?></h2>
        <h2>Course : <?php echo $student_course ?></h2>
        <h2>Semester : <?php echo $student_semester ?></h2>

<?php 
}}

 $stmnt->close();
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Add PDO exception code there so that exact error you can get?

Comment: iss `$_SESSION['student_roll']` definitiveley set?  I would check that using `isset`

Comment: Yeah, i can echo that.

Comment: Add -  `or die($conn->errorInfo());` with your prepare statement and check

Comment: I'm getting this error.

http://i.imgur.com/Ry7ElKZ.png?1

Comment: use `try catch` statements so that you would be able to know ur errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution by myself. Thanks for giving me your time btw!

The correct solution is:

```
        $student_roll = $row["roll"];
        $student_name = $row["firstname"];
        $student_course = $row["lastname"];
        $student_semester = $row["course"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you something alternative is called redbenaphp.

How can you do the same things in readbeanphp.

1. Download rb.zip & unzip it & your file is rb.php

Now the the the code as follow:

```
<?php

     session_start();
     include "rb.php";

     $student_rollno = $_SESSION['student_roll'];

     require('../includes/connect.php');

$result=R::getAll("SELECT students.roll, students.firstname, students.lastname, students.course, students.semester FROM students,teachers WHERE students.roll = ? AND students.semester = teachers.semester ",array($student_rollno));

foreach($result as $row){
 $student_roll = $row["students.roll"];
        $student_name = $row["students.firstname"];
        $student_course = $row["students.lastname"];
        $student_semester = $row["students.course"];
         ?>



         <h1>Hello <?php echo $student_roll; ?>. Your details are : </h1><br><br>
            <h2>Roll No : <?php echo $student_name ?></h2>
            <h2>Course : <?php echo $student_course ?></h2>
            <h2>Semester : <?php echo $student_semester ?></h2>

    <?php 
    }

?>
```

Edit your config.php file as follow:

```
<?php
 R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase',
        'user', 'password' ); //for both mysql or mariaDB
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but i think using this method will take my more time in first understanding it and then implementing it to my project. What would you suggest?

Comment: If you would need to use pdo then go with redbeanphp it will save your time a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you first selecting `teachers.semester` from teachers table  as your query is containing `students.semester = teachers.semester` ?

your SQL query is selecting from students table only .

```
you need to fetch `teachers.semester` from teachers table also.
```